# Nested loops within terraform module for Azure FrontDoor

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-front-door

I'm trying to deploy a list of Azure Front Doors and their custom https configuration resources. I have a list of Azure Front Door resources which are deployed like this pseudo code. They work correctly (although without custom https configuration)

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "front_door" {
  count = length(local.frontdoors)
... config
}
```

I then try and add some terraform to create the custom https configuration as described here and use[terraform azure frontdoor custom https config docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/frontdoor_custom_https_configuration) the following fragment:

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "custom_https_configuration" {
  count                             = length(local.frontdoors)
  for_each                          = { for frontend in azurerm_frontdoor.front_door[count.index].frontend_endpoint : frontend.id => frontend_id }
  frontend_endpoint_id              = each.value.frontend_id
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = each.key != "front_door" ? local.frontend_https_configurations[each.key].custom_https_provisioning_enabled : false
  dynamic "custom_https_configuration" {
    for_each = (each.key != "front_door" ? local.frontend_https_configurations[each.key].custom_https_provisioning_enabled : false) ? [1] : []
    content {
      certificate_source                         = "AzureKeyVault"
      azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name    = XXXX
      azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_version = XXXX
      azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id       = XXXX
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this syntax error:

Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"

if i try and remove the count, and use the for_each structure instead:

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "custom_https_configuration" {
  for_each                          = { 
      for frontdoor in azurerm_frontdoor.front_door :
      [
        for key, value in frontdoor.frontend_endpoint: value.frontend.id => frontend_id
      ]
  }
  frontend_endpoint_id              = each.value.frontend_id
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = each.key != "front_door" ? local.frontend_https_configurations[each.key].custom_https_provisioning_enabled : false
  dynamic "custom_https_configuration" {
    for_each = (each.key != "front_door" ? local.frontend_https_configurations[each.key].custom_https_provisioning_enabled : false) ? [1] : []
    content {
      certificate_source                         = "AzureKeyVault"
      azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name    = XXXX
      azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_version = XXXX
      azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id       = XXXX
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error instead:

Error: Invalid 'for' expression

on main.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "custom_https_configuration":
173:   for_each                          = {
174:       for frontdoor in azurerm_frontdoor.front_door :
175:       [
176:         for key, value in frontdoor.frontend_endpoint: value.frontend.id => frontend_id
177:       ]
178:   }

Key expression is required when building an object.

How can i have a nested loop so that i can successfully deploy a f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to nest `for` loops, you need to use the [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html) function (for lists) or the [merge](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html) function in combination with the `...` list expansion operator (for maps).

Basically, like so:

```
// To make a list
for_each = flatten([
  for idx1, val1 in var.list1:
  [
    for idx2, val2 in val2.list_field:
      // Here is where you construct whatever value/object for each element
  ]
])

// To make a list
for_each = merge([
  for key1, val1 in var.map1:
  {
    for key2, val2 in val1.map_field:
    // Some key/value pair, such as:
    "${key1}-${key2}" => val2
  }
]...)
```

You also have your map comprehension key/value reversed. Try this:

```
for_each = merge([ 
      for idx, frontdoor in azurerm_frontdoor.front_door :
      {
        for key, value in frontdoor.frontend_endpoints: 
        "${idx}-${key}" => {
           endpoint_key = key
           endpoint_id = value
        }
      }
  ]...)
```

And now within your resource, you can use `each.value.endpoint_key` and `each.value.endpoint_id`.